# google map not showing after publishing?

Tags: android, dictionary

My app work fine, but  when i publish that my app, map does not show.
My apps build version is release. 
1. Get SHA1 keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
2. Add package name and SHA1 to API console and get API
3. Add API to google_map_api.xml
I use those stpes, but my apps map does not show after publish
I need to help, Thanks

Comment: you have to add your api key to both debug & release config files

Comment: I have both debug and release api keys. My Apps Android manifest have  android:value="@string/google_maps_key"

Comment: My build variant is release.

Comment: make sure that you use same key in manifest and google_map_api.xml which is your release key

Comment: Yes . Some times I add to direct release api key to android manifest like android:value="AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" But map doesnt work after publish